# BlueCove in Mac OSX BluetoothAddress issues

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm having some issues with BlueCove(version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT) on Mac OS X (10.10.2) using Eclipse + JDK 1.7. Where both address and name seems to be null, thus I cannot connect to it.

```
LocalDevice myDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
myDevice.isPowerOn(); //returns true
myDevice.getFriendlyName(); //returns null
myDevice.getProperty("bluetooth.api.version"); //returns "1.1.1"
myDevice.getBluetoothAddress(); //returns "000000000000"
```

Any suggestion what might be causing these problems?